# Answer prints 0 not actual answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def difference1():
    answer = 0
    for a in range(1, 100):
        sum1 = a**2
        sum1 += answer
    print(answer)
difference1()
```

why is my code printing 0? I want to get all the numbers between 1 and 100's squares added together. I probably have just made a dumb mistake but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Because you do not change `answer` anywhere. `sum1 += answer` is equivalent to `sum1 = sum1 + answer`. No assignment to `answer` is made.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `answer` to `sum1`, when you should be adding `sum1` to `answer`!

Also, you have a mistake in your `range`: it goes up to *but not including* the stop-value:

```
def sum_of_squares(upto):
    answer = 0
    for i in range(1, upto + 1):
        answer += i*i
    return answer

print(sum_of_squares(100))    # => 338350
```

---

For bonus points, it could also be written as

```
def sum_of_squares(upto):
    # turn the loop into a generator expression
    return sum(i*i for i in range(1, upto + 1))
```

or as

```
def sum_of_squares(upto):
    # sum of squares formula
    return upto * (upto + 1) * (2*upto + 1) // 6
```

Comment: Good! Feel free to accept it as a solution by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the 'answer' varaible, thats why it always 0 as you assigned it.

Do this:

```
def difference1():
    answer = 0
    for a in range(1, 100):
        sum1 = a**2
        answer += sum1 #the change is on this line
    print(answer)
difference1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding to the wrong variable, you want:

```
answer += sum1
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line, `sum1 += answer`, you have declared answer as `0` and are adding it to `sum1`. It currently looks like this: `sum1 = sum1 + 0`. You want it to look like this: `answer = answer + sum1`. Therefore, use this expression instead: `answer += sum1`.

Answer (score 0):

you had an incorrect range and you added your answer to `sum1` and and not adding `answer` to `sum`

you can directly add `a**2` to `answer`

```
def difference1():
    answer = 0
    for a in range(101)
        answer += a**2
    return answer
print(difference1())
```